# iOS Mobile Safari scrolling: DOM manipulation while decelerating?

Tags: ios, dom, mobile-safari

In iOS MObile Safari, after flicking to scroll, is it possible to manipulate the DOM while the system is in deceleration mode? I tested this by constantly incrementing a number in a fix-positioned element on the page using setInterval and I noticed the DOM doesn't update when scrolling. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, iOS freezes DOM manipulation when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

No. If you want to run javascript in response to scrolling, your only solution is to use programmatic scrolling (iScroller, zynga-scroller).